# Using variables in Gradle build script

Tags: groovy, gradle

I am using Gradle in my project. I have a task for doing some extra configuration with my war. I need to build a string to use in my task like, lets say I have:

```
task extraStuff{
    doStuff 'org.springframework:spring-web:3.0.6.RELEASE@war'
}
```

This works fine. What I need to do is define version (actually already defined in properties file) and use this in the task like:

```
springVersion=3.0.6.RELEASE

task extraStuff{
    doStuff 'org.springframework:spring-web:${springVersion}@war'
}
```

My problem is spring version is not recognised as variable. So how can I pass it inside the string?

Comment: Don't forget, you can break it out as well: `doStuff group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: ${springVersion}, ext: 'war'`

Comment: Don't forget, you can remove the parenthesis `{}` from `${spingVersion}` as well: `doStuff group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: $springVersion, ext: 'war'`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I think the problem may lay on string literal delimiters:

1. The string literals are defined exactly as in `groovy` so enclose  it in single or double quotes (e.g. `"3.0.6.RELEASE"`);
2. `Gstrings` are not parsed in single quotes strings (both single `'...'` or triple `'''...'''` ones) if i recall correctly;

So the code will be:

```
springVersion = '3.0.6.RELEASE' //or with double quotes "..."

task extraStuff{
    doStuff "org.springframework:spring-web:${springVersion}@war"
}
```

Comment: True. Changing from single to double quotes fixed my problem

Answer (score 105):

If you're developing an **Android** application using **Gradle**, you can declare a variable (i.e holding a dependency version) thanks to the keyword **`def`** like below:

```
def version = '1.2'
    
dependencies {
  compile "groupId:artifactId:${version}"
}
```

Answer (score 20):

On android there are actually 2 possibilities how to achieve this. It really depends which suits your needs. Those two possibilities have their pros and cons. You can use `def` variable or `ext{}` block. Variable `def` is awesome because it lets you click on the variable and points exactly where it is defined in the file compared to `ext{}` block which does NOT points to that exact variable. On the other hand `ext{}` has one good advantage and that is you can refer variables from `project_name/build.gradle` to `project_name/app/build.gradle` which in some cases is very useful BUT as I said if you click on that variable lets say only inside only one file it wont points out to the definition of that variable which is very bad because it takes you more search time if your dependency list grows.

**1) def option which is propably best and saves you search time.**

```
def lifecycle = '2.0.0'

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle'
}
```

**2) second ext{} block. Its kinda ok if dependency list is not huge.**

```
ext {
    lifecycle = '1.1.1'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle'
}
```

**3) In some cases if you want to share variables between** `project_name/build.gradle` **and** `project_name/app/build.gradle` **use ext{}**

in *project_name/build.gradle* you define `kotlin_shared_variable`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_shared_variable = '1.3.41'

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_shared_variable"
    }
}
```

which you can use in *project_name/app/build.gradle*

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_shared_variable"
}
```

and of course you can combine them.

Comment: So, the `ext{}` option works, but I cannot override that property using the `-Plifecycle=2.0.0` command-line flag. The only way I've seen to do this is by providing the property in `gradle.properties`. Is that the recommended way of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

You can also define variables in the **gradle.properties** file at the root of your project. You don't have to use double quotes in that file. You would need to add the following line:

`lifecycle=2.0.0`

Comment: the `ext { }` approach did not work for me however this one did. so 1 vote to Doctor

Answer (score 0):

see [here](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation).

> Double-quoted strings are plain java.lang.String if there’s no interpolated expression, but are groovy.lang.GString instances if interpolation is present.

Gradle uses Groovy as a DSL. Here "${springVersion}" is a placeholder, what you want is to interpolate, so you should use the double quote, only the double quote in GString has the capability to interpolate.